# How to query a (Postgres) RDS DB through an AWS Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

I'm trying to query an RDS (Postgres) database through Python, more specifically a Jupyter Notebook. Overall, what I've been trying for now is:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds-data')

response = client.execute_sql(
    awsSecretStoreArn='string',
    database='string',
    dbClusterOrInstanceArn='string',
    schema='string',
    sqlStatements='string'
)
```

The error I've been receiving is:

```
BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ExecuteSql operation: ERROR: invalid cluster id: arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:839600708595:db:zprime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was much simpler than I thought, nothing fancy or specific. It was basically a solution I had used before when accessing one of my local DBs. Simply `import` a specific library for your database type (Postgres, MySQL, etc) and then connect to it in order to execute queries through python.

I don't know if it will be the best solution since making queries through python will probably be much slower than doing them directly, but it's what works for now.

```py
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database = 'database_name',
                        user =     'user',
                        password = 'password',
                        host =     'host',
                        port =     'port')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
            SELECT *
            FROM table;
            ''')

cur.fetchall()
```